# Querying a perimeter around a Geocode-Location (Lat/Lon)

Tags: sql, google-maps, distance, geocode

how can I search for geo-objects in a certain perimeter ? E.g. I have several objects with Lat/Lon coordinates stored in my DB. Now I want to retrieve all the objects which lie in a specific perimeter (10 miles or 20 miles) around a given point.

I guess what I would have to do is to form some query like:

```
SELECT * FROM objects o where o.lat < (myPositionLat+x) AND o.lon < (myPositionLon+y)
```

Is this right? How do I determine/set the values for x and y?

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep in mind that the distance between longitudes is not constant. Degrees of latitude are parallel and are approximately 111 kilometers (69 miles) apart, but a degree of longitude is widest at the equator at 111 kilometers and gradually converges to zero at the poles.

At 40° north or south the distance between a degree of longitude is about 85 kilometers (53 miles), while the distance between latitudes remains roughly the same at 111 kilometers  ([Source](http://geography.about.com/library/faq/blqzdistancedegree.htm)). If your geo-objects will be limited to a certain area only, and a very rough filter is acceptable, you can use this information to determine your `x` and `y` offsets.

However if your objects will be sparse around the globe, you should be calculating the [great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) instead. Luckily this is relatively easy with the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). You may want to read further and check out the implementation at [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) by Chris Veness.

If you will only have a handful of geo-objects, you can simply calculate the great-circle distance from your point to each geo-object. Then simply sort the result list by the distance, and filter by some threshold in miles or kilometers.

However, if you will be having many geo-objects, you should consider using a database with [spatial indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index) capabilities. [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/spatial-extensions.html), [PostgreSQL](http://postgis.refractions.net/) and [SQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/spatial-data.aspx) all have geo-spatial features (either natively or via extensions), which include spatial indexing and implementations of the haversine formula.